# ProductFlavors - some classes does not compile

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I've a technical question about productFlavors, that is, when I have more than one type of a same app some especific classes (of just one flavor for example) depending on of BuildVariant choosen don't compile. Ok I get it. But then how I can reference them of a common class? Because unless that I choose the especific flavor (that use this classes) the whole app don't compile.
I'm just a student, but I think that who work with this should have a easier way, than look for the whole code and disable the classes of the other flavor...

my code

in gradle.build

```
productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "com.example.flavors.free"
        }

        pro {
            applicationId "com.example.flavors.pro"
        }
    }
```

In the common activity I make this verification

```
public boolean isPro() {
        return "pro".equals(BuildConfig.FLAVOR);
    }
```

and try this code

```
if (isPro()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Versão Pro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

//            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BannerActivity.class));

        }
```

This BannerActivity is especific of a free flavor (created in free flavor folder), then when I use the other BuilderVariant (of pro flavor), if I don't disable this activity, the whole code does not work (not compile)...
Just one activity is easy to disable, but and when there is many?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can create empty BannerActivity in the pro flavor. It will not be used, but your app will compile.
2. You can make two versions of calling activity in each flavor. In the free version you'll have `startActivity()`, in the pro – `Toast.makeText()`

Comment: It works. But the packages's names have to be the same in src/nameFlavor/packageName, if these packageName were different, the code also does not compile because the imports will be differents too. Thank you.